# trying to group by, returning on a specified value, and summing rows on another value in R

Tags: r

I think I have the right idea but could use some help. I have something similar to below, where I'm trying to find the numerator and denominator of occurrences for `ID3`.

I have everything except `want`, `den`, and `num`.

`want` is the `ID` of interest based on when `ID2`==0 by `group`.

`num` is the numerator of occurrences where val==1 for a given `ID3` by `want` (example, ID3==1 is associated with F and B, B is associated with val==1, therefore numerator for ID3==1 is 1 and denominator is 2), and `den` is the denominator of occurences for a given `ID3`.

I think I can solve `den` by using UniqueN of `want` by ID3, but not sure how to get `num`.

please help me solve want, den and num!

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
               ID2=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
               ID3=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2),
               group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2, 3, 3),
               val=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
               want=c('B','B','B','D', 'D', 'D', 'F', 'F'),
               den=c(2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2),
               num=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1))

df

  ID ID2 ID3 group val want den num
1  A   1   1     1   1    B   2   1
2  B   0   2     1   1    B   2   1
3  A   1   3     1   1    B   1   0
4  C   1   4     2   0    D   1   0
5  C   1   5     2   0    D   1   0
6  D   0   6     2   0    D   1   0
7  E   1   1     3   0    F   2   1
8  F   0   2     3   0    F   2   1
```

Comment: For 'num' are you calculating val = 1 for each 'ID3', then the values are not matching

Comment: it is val==1 or 0 by ```group```, in this case ID3 =1 had val=1 and ID3=2 had val =1 both one time, so for ID3==1 and 2 their num is 1

Comment: val is grouped by ```group```, but in order to calculate num and den I am assuming we will need to group by ID3, or something equivalent. I was thinking UniqueN, but am stumped with ```num```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a comparison to subset the values after grouping by

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(group) %>% 
     mutate(want = ID[ID2==0]) %>%
     group_by(ID3) %>%
     mutate(num = +(n_distinct(want) > 1 & any(val == 1)), den = n())
# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   ID3 [6]
#  ID      ID2   ID3 group   val want    den   num
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <int> <int>
#1 A         1     1     1     1 B         2     1
#2 B         0     2     1     1 B         2     1
#3 A         1     3     1     1 B         1     0
#4 C         1     4     2     0 D         1     0
#5 C         1     5     2     0 D         1     0
#6 D         0     6     2     0 D         1     0
#7 E         1     1     3     0 F         2     1
#8 F         0     2     3     0 F         2     1
```

Or another option is `match`

```
df %>% 
      group_by(group) %>%
      mutate(want = ID[match(0, ID2)])
```